# Automatically exchange QGIS layer datasources during project opening?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins

Do you know of any existing QGIS plugin that automatically exchanges layer datasources during opening of a Project?

I would like to transparently switch our users from "PostGIS A" server to "PostGIS B" using a predefined datasource mapping.

We are on QGIS 2.18 for Windows

Using a script is not an option for us. I like more the idea of hooking into the project open event/signal and change the datasource there.

Comment: sed script on the project file before opening?

Comment: using a script is not an option for us. I like more the idea of hooking into the project open event/signal and change the datasource there.

Comment: BTW we are on QGIS 2.18 for Windows.

Comment: Have a look at the changeDataSource plugin. It's not automatic but it might save you some steps.

Comment: I’m already using this Plugin, but I would like a transparent mechanism for our users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS 3.x it's easy to solve this problem using the *QgsPathResolver* class. Therefor I created a custom plugin that implements a custom path preprocessor. When opening a project all old PostGIS server names (oldPGServer) are replaced by new ones (newPGServer) and user and password entries are always removed, because we use SSPI on Windows now. If the project is stored in a GPKG file and the file was moved to a different directory, the GPKG datasources are automatically repaired.

****init**.py**

```py
def classFactory(iface): 
    from .changeServerPath import changeServerPath
    return changeServerPath(iface)
```

**changeServerPath.py**

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPathResolver,QgsProject,QgsMessageLog,Qgis
import re

class changeServerPath:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.gpkgProjectName = ''
        QgsProject.instance().metadataChanged.connect(self.changedMetadata)

    def initGui(self):
        self.processor = QgsPathResolver.setPathPreprocessor(self.my_processor)

    def unload(self):
        QgsPathResolver.removePathPreprocessor(self.processor)

    def changedMetadata(self):
        self.gpkgProjectName = ''
        m = re.search('[^/]+\.gpkg',QgsProject.instance().fileName(),flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if m:
            self.gpkgProjectName = m.group(0)

    def my_processor(self,path):
        if re.search('oldPGServer[\s./]',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---------------------------------------------','MyMessages',Qgis.Info)
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Replace Layer Source: %s' % path,'MyMessages',Qgis.Info)
            path = re.sub('oldPGServer[^\s/]*','newPGServer',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            path = re.sub('user=[^\s]+\s','',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            path = re.sub('password=[^\s]+\s','',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('with: %s' % path,'MyMessages',Qgis.Info)

        # Replacing GPKG datasources if project is stored in GPKG
        if self.gpkgProjectName:
            if re.search('[^/]+\.gpkg',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                if not re.search(self.gpkgProjectName,path,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---------------------------------------------','MyMessages',Qgis.Info)
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Replace Layer Source: %s' % path,'MyMessages',Qgis.Info)
                    path = re.sub('[^/]+\.gpkg',self.gpkgProjectName,path,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('with: %s' % path,'MyMessages',Qgis.Info)

        return path
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear how you use the `self.processor` in the end. You seem to be solving your issue only with regular expressions. Could you please explain?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo you are correct that I only use Regex to change the path in *my_processor*. `self.processor` is only used for reference, so that I can remove the path preprocessor during unload of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In my desperate aim to solve this problem, I managed to transparently replace vector and raster datasources during project opening.

But unfortunately, this only works as long as the old datasources are still available. If QGIS discovers a broken datasource, the internal bad layer handler is called, showing the default repair dialog.

The "changeDataSource" plugin therefor uses a custom BadLayerHandler, but I really would like to keep the default dialog for all the other datasources which should be manually repaired. I'm searching for a mechanism to replace the internal project XML (QDomDocument) during project opening, so that the default bad layer handling is still available. It would also give me a chance to change symbol, font and image paths as well. But I guess that this won't be possible using QGis' Python API.